# Select Distinct returning multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, distinct

I've got a query that is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1, b.field2, a.field4 
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON b.fielda = a.fieldb 
WHERE a.field1 = 'xxxx'
```

I run this and it returns three xxxx rows.  I need all of the information listed above with the first field being distinct.  Do I have the correct syntax for this?

Comment: If you only want the first one to be `distinct`, what values should the other columns have?  What determines the order of the first match?  Also, which database -- you tagged multiple...

Comment: This `distinct` applies to all fields you listed.

Comment: some sample data would be nice also

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Postgres?

Comment: In Postgres you can use `distinct on (..) ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (a.field1) a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1, b.field2, a.field4
from table1 a join
     table2 b
     on b.fielda = a.fieldb
where a.field1 = 'xxxx'
order by a.field1;
```

In either Postgres or SQL Server, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select ab.*
from (select a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1, b.field2, a.field4,
             row_number() over (partition by a.field1 order by a.field1) as seqnum
      from table1 a join
           table2 b
           on b.fielda = a.fieldb
      where a.field1 = 'xxxx'
     ) ab
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or, since you only want one row, you can use `limit`/`top`:

```
select a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1, b.field2, a.field4
from table1 a join
     table2 b
     on b.fielda = a.fieldb
where a.field1 = 'xxxx'
limit 1;
```

In SQL Server:

```
select top 1 a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1, b.field2, a.field4
from table1 a join
     table2 b
     on b.fielda = a.fieldb
where a.field1 = 'xxxx';
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `row_number()`:

```
with cte as (
    select distinct a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1, b.field2, a.field4,
          row_number() over (partition by a.field1 order by a.field1) rn
    from table1 a
        join table2 b on b.fielda = a.fieldb 
    where a.field1 = 'xxxx'
    )
select * 
from cte
where rn = 1
```

But you need to define which record to take.  This orders by `field1` which essentially will take a random record...

Answer (score 0):

As you can read from your comments, DISTINCT cannot work for you. It gives you distinct *rows*. What you need instead is an aggregation, so as to get from three records to only one.

So the first comment you got (by sgeddes) is already the answer you need: "what values should the other columns have?". How shall the dbms know? You didn't tell it.

One row per field1 usually means GROUP BY field1. Then for every other field decide what you want to see: The maximum of field2 maybe? The minimum of field3? The avarage of field4?

```
select a.field1, max(a.field2), min(a.field3), count(b.field1), sum(b.field2), avg(a.field4) 
from table1 a
join table2 b on b.fielda = a.fieldb
where a.field1 = 'xxxx'
group by a.field1;
```